# LabelListAttribute example?

Tags: acumatica

I have a field in a Database that is set as a varchar(1), and it is bound to a non editable textbox in acumatica. I would like it so that when the value of the field is equal to 'A', the value displayed in the textbox in Acumatica is something longer such as 'Apple'. The user will not be editing the textbox so I do not need this to work in reverse.

From my research, I see that LabelListAttribute might be the attribute I am looking for. Can anyone give me an example on how one creates a new 'LabelProviderType' or 'LabelValuePair' to feed into this attribute.

Additionally, am I just better off in copying the combobox example from the T100 class (Page 76) and disabling it? I would rather this work within a textbox

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the use case you are describing you should indeed use a `PXDropDown` control bounded to a DAC field decorated with `PXStringList` attribute as described in T100 Configuring a Combo Box example.